# mysql update query -

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I am trying to update a row in database  skadate_profile with this code

```
   if (!isset($_COOKIE["lastlogin"]))
 {
 setcookie("lastlogin", $current_cookie, mktime(23, 59, 59, date("m"), date("d"), date("y")) , "/", "", 0);
 $result8 = mysql_query("UPDATE skadate_profile SET time_left = 600, cookie = '".$current_cookie."',todays_date = '".$todays_date."' where profile_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($avconfig['siteId'])."' limit 1");
 $cook = $_COOKIE["lastlogin"]; //users PC cookie
 //echo "RESULT   ", $result8;
    //echo "Here setting cookie to   ", $cook;
      } else {
     //echo "Cookie was prev set and is  ", $cook;
 }
```

$result8 gives a value of 1

can someone assist me?

Comment: why it should give something different from 1?

Comment: What is the problem? Did the database not have the specified table updated?

Comment: What do you mean by `$result8 gives a value of 1`? if you mean that it's only giving you the ONE result, it's because of `limit 1`

Comment: @Fred-ii- `UPDATE` will not give you any results, no matter how you'll set limit :)

Comment: @ElonThan Yes I know, I was just about to edit my comment stating that the OP wasn't querying to "show" results. Question is vague IMO. Am not sure of what are the expected results.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify the question, the UPDATE did not update the values in the specified database table

Answer (score 4):

1 means success.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Return Values

> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Comment: It's not really `1`, it's `true`.